# Android hierarchical preferences

Tags: android

I'm writing a web service client and have the three obvious settings: url, username and password. For this the key value pairs in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) would be enough. But I hit a roadblock when I wanted to subscribe to more than one server instance. What I need is the three settings stored once for each server instance added by the user. Whats the best approach here? Create a custom settings activity and save it to a [file](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)?

Comment: Don't save them to a file, use a different `SharedPreferences` name for each preference and _Android_ will save them to a file for you (maybe, maybe it will store it in a better place)

Answer (score 0):

You can store a `Set<String>` in the `SharedPreferences`. You can use this to store the keys to the other properties.

One way of doing this is to store a set with keys that define each of your servers (for example, "foo.com" and "bar.com"). Then for each server store the properties you need using a known suffix. Lets say you need to the store the username and password for each one, then you would put "foo.com-username" and "foo.com-password" as the keys for the username and password for the "foo.com" server, same with "bar.com".

Comment: I assume then that you populate your `PreferenceFragment` dynamically rather than through xml? Or do you use a custom `Activity` entirely?

Comment: I think you can still use a `PreferenceFragment` or `PreferenceActivity`, you would need to create a custom `Preference` control to handle your case. Remember you can define custom preference controls within your xml just like you do with custom views in xml layouts.